# How to properly bundle a Language Server extension for VScode with client and server inside

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have created my first vscode extension and I'm trying to bundle the javascript files using webpack

These are the instructions that I've been following
https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/publishing-extension.

But those instructions are for a single app that contains out, src, and node_modules at the top level, Language Server extension contains two main folders `client` and `server`, each with their own folders: `src, out, node_modules`

[image]

When running the `vsce package` I get this warning

```
This extension consists of 413 files, out of which 122 are JavaScript files. For performance reasons, you should bundle your 
extension: https://aka.ms/vscode-bundle-extension . You should also exclude unnecessary files by adding them to your .vscodeignore: https://aka.ms/vscode-vscodeignore
 DONE  Packaged: D:\MAO\repos\Petrel-XML\petrel-xml-0.9.1.vsix (413 files, 416.32KB)
```

So I´m using this .vscodeignore

```
.vscode
**/*.ts
**/*.map
out/**
node_modules/**
test_files/**
client/src/**
server/src/**
tsconfig.json
webpack.config.js
.gitignore
```

Also the documentation is a bit obsolete regarding the webpack.config.js, so I had to wrap the 'use strict' into a function with all the settings.

The `entry` setting was changed according to my needs

```js
//@ts-check

(function () {
  'use strict';

  const path = require('path');

  /**@type {import('webpack').Configuration}*/
  const config = {
    target: 'node', // vscode extensions run in a Node.js-context  -> https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/

    entry: './client/src/extension.ts', // the entry point of this extension,  -> https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/
    output: {
      // the bundle is stored in the 'dist' folder (check package.json),  -> https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
      filename: 'extension.js',
      clean: true, //clean the dist folder for each time webpack is run
      libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
      devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: '../[resource-path]'
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    externals: {
      vscode: 'commonjs vscode' // the vscode-module is created on-the-fly and must be excluded. Add other modules that cannot be webpack'ed,  -> https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/
    },
    resolve: {
      // support reading TypeScript and JavaScript files,  -> https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader
      extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.ts$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'ts-loader'
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  };
  module.exports = config;
}());
```

And in the package.json I have this section.

```
"scripts": {
    "vscode:prepublish": "webpack --mode production",
    "webpack": "webpack --mode development",
    "webpack-dev": "webpack --mode development --watch",
    "test-compile": "tsc -p ./",
    "compile": "tsc -b",
    "watch": "tsc -b -w",
    "postinstall": "cd client && npm install && cd ../server && npm install && cd ..",
    "test": "sh ./scripts/e2e.sh"
},
```

Even after doing all the above the package is created but with the same "bundle warning performance" message I need to know how to correctly bundle it by removing that warning message and keep the extension working.

**UPDATE**: Current Microsoft documentation does not explain how to pack client and server extensions (Language Server extensions) - the current documentation about webpack for "regular" extension is here - https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/bundling-extension - that is how is done like that

Comment: Does the "vscode:prepublish" script is the one that is run and after which the error is shown? You have structured two projects (client and server) and yet you have one entry point in webpack, why?

Comment: Current Microsoft documentation does not explain how to pack client and server extensions (Language Server extensions) - the current documentation about webpack for "regular" extension is here - https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/bundling-extension - that is how is done like that

Comment: I skimmed over the documentation, and I understand they have example for the simples extension (hard to cover many cases in documentation). What I ask for still remains unanswered: do you get that message when you run "vscode:prepublish" or other scripts? (if other don't worry, since those are not production optimized)You probably need to look at webpack documentation - https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/  and add tag on question for "webpack"

Comment: vscode>prepublish is one of the first commands that is executed

Comment: I have over viewed the document you mention and as fars as concept goes is useful, but don't know how to apply it for my scenario. The client is the entry points and it depends on the server, but each are separated processes

Answer (score 0):

To understand how to do it just follow next steps:

1. Clone repository of `vscode-yaml`
2. Download `vscode-yaml-*.vsix` package
3. Unpack `vscode-yaml-*.vsix` package in some folder
4. Compare webpack config in cloned repository with result in unpacked package

The main key: you have to pack together language client entry point, language server entry point, their `package.json`'s and their complementary files (as syntaxes, configs, readme, etc.)